# Using aggregate function in the materialized view, getting wrong output

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I want to dedupe the events coming into events table
My source table,

```
create table events (
  date DateTime, 
  cust_id String, 
  event_type String,  
  status String
) ENGINE = MergeTree() ORDER BY date;
```

materialized view destination table

```
create table events_unique (
  timestamp AggregateFunction(max, DateTime), 
  cust_id String, 
  event_type String,  
  status AggregateFunction(argMax, String, DateTime) 
) ENGINE = MergeTree() ORDER BY cust_id;
```

Materialized view definition

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW events_mt TO events_unique AS
SELECT maxState(date) as timestamp,cust_id,event_type,argMaxState(status, date) FROM events GROUP BY cust_id,event_type;
```

inserting events to events table

```
insert into events (*) VALUES (now(),'1','ONBOARD','fail')
insert into events (*) VALUES (now(),'1','ONBOARD','succ')
```

Expected output

```
┌─maxMerge(timestamp)─┬─cust_id─┬─event_type─┬─argMaxMerge(status)─┐
│ 2022-02-15 12:29:40 │ 1       │ ONBOARD    │ succ                │
└─────────────────────┴─────────┴────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

My output

```
┌─maxMerge(timestamp)─┬─cust_id─┬─event_type─┬─argMaxMerge(status)─┐
│ 2022-02-15 12:29:40 │ 1       │ ONBOARD    │                     │
└─────────────────────┴─────────┴────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 0):

I did not aliased my destination table column in the materialized view

Correct materialized view is:-

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW events_mt TO events_unique AS
SELECT maxState(date) as timestamp,cust_id,event_type,argMaxState(status, date) as status FROM events GROUP BY cust_id,event_type;
```

Clickhouse should give some error in this case, like no target column found.  Keeping this question open.

Comment: it's intentional!!!

https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/28267#issuecomment-907320138